# datatable not able to set the id using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a table for which i set the data on load and try to refresh on ajax request. I am not able to set the attribute , id for each td. And also since i want to hide few columns,i put the bvisible as false. Due to this the td itself is disappearing and so i am not able to get the data on click of the td in the table.

on load, we get the data for history as follows,

```
  var historydata ='{history_result= <tr><td id="sid"> 1</td><td id="sid1">2</td><td id="sid3">123</td><td style="display:none;" id="txt1">test</td><td style="display:none;" id="txt2">a</td><td style="display:none;" id="txt3"></td><td style="display:none;" id="txt4"></td><td style="display:none;" id="txt5"></td><td style="display:none;" id="input1">input1</td><td style="display:none;" id="input2">input2</td><td style="display:none;" id="input3">input3</td><td style="display:none;" id="input4">input4</td><td style="display:none;" id="input5">input5</td><td style="display:none;" id="datainput"> data </td></tr>}';
$('#gridResult').append(historydata);
    $("#gridResult").dataTable({
          "iDisplayLength": 5,            
           "aLengthMenu": [[5,10,20], [5,10,20]],
            "bLengthChange": false
    });

});
```

I here by set the table in my html code as follows,

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="gridResult">                                                                     
<thead>
 <tr class="active">
    <th>sid</th>
    <th>sid1</th>
     <th>sid3</th>
      <th style="display: none">input1</th>
      <th style="display: none">input2</th>
      <th style="display: none">input3</th>
      <th style="display: none">input4</th>
      <th style="display: none">input5</th>
      <th style="display: none">txt1</th>
      <th style="display: none">txt2</th>
      <th style="display: none">txt3</th>
       <th style="display: none">txt4</th>
       <th style="display: none">txt5</th>
      <th style="display: none">datainput</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   </table>
```

In Ajax request, we set the data in the gridResult as follows,
Data format from ajax is as follows,

```
    var historydata = {"history_result":[[1,"0.075","106","","fname","","","","data","data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"],[2,"0.001","1","lname","a","","","","newdata1","newdata2","newdata3","newdata4","newdata5","newdata6"]]}';
```

I am setting the data by using this way.

```
               var arySearchHistory = [];
               for (var i=3; i <= 13; i++ ) {                                               arySearchHistory.push({
                                        "aTargets": [i], 
                                        "bVisible": false                                   
                                    });
                                    };
                                    $('#gridResult') .dataTable({                                                                                    
                                            "aaData" : history_result,
                                               "aLengthMenu": [[5,10,20], [5,10,20]],
                                               "iDisplayLength": 5,
                                                "aoColumnDefs":  arySearchHistory,
                                                "bDestroy": true,                                                   
                                                "bLengthChange": false
                                    });
```

We are not able to set the id in the data table in the "aoColumnDefs". since we put the bVisible as false,we are not able to see the td in the table.

On Click, we need to get the data by using the following code.

```
   $('#gridResult').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).find("td").each(function() {            
        var key = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).html();
            alert(value);
        if (key == "input1")
            $('#sid').val(value);
        if (key == 'input2')
            $('#sid2').val(value);
        if (key == 'input3')
            $('#sid3').val(value);
        if (key == "input4")
            $('#sid4').val(value);
        if (key == "input5")
            $('#sid5').val(value);
        if (key == "txt1")
            $('#txt1').val(value);
        if (key == 'txt2')
            $('#txt2').val(value);
        if (key == 'txt3')
            $('#txt3').val(value);
        if (key == "txt4")
            $('#txt4').val(value);
        if (key == "txt5")
            $('#txt5').val(value);
        if (key == "Query") {
             // todo: on click of the data, we need to do some functionality here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of setting bVisible as false, try set sClass as hidden ( {sClass: "hidden"} ). I think it will help also with the id attribute.